# How can I use IF statements in Teradata without using BTEQ

Tags: teradata

I'm trying to create some deployment tools and I don't want to use BTEQ.  I've been trying to work with the Teradata.Client.Provider in PowerShell but I'm getting syntax errors on the creation of a table.

> [Teradata Database] [3706] Syntax error: expected something between
>   ';' and the 'IF' keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM DBC.TablesV WHERE DatabaseName = DATABASE AND TableName = 'MyTable';
IF ACTIVITYCOUNT > 0 THEN GOTO EndStep1;

CREATE MULTISET TABLE MyTable ,
    NO FALLBACK ,
    NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
    NO AFTER JOURNAL,
    CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
        (
            MyColId         INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                                                    (START WITH 1
                                                    INCREMENT BY 1
                                                    MINVALUE 0
                                                    MAXVALUE 2147483647 
                                                    NO CYCLE)
                                                    NOT NULL,
            MyColType           VARCHAR(50)     NULL,
            MyColTarget     VARCHAR(128)    NULL,
            MyColScriptName VARCHAR(256)    NULL,
            MyColOutput     VARCHAR(64000)  NULL,
            isMyColException    BYTEINT(1)      NULL,
            ExceptionOutput         VARCHAR(64000)  NULL,
            MyColBuild          VARCHAR(128)    NULL,
            MyColDate           TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL
        )
    PRIMARY INDEX PI_MyTable_MyColLogId(MyColLogId);

LABEL EndStep1;
```

I would rather not use BTEQ as I've not found it has worked well in other deployment tools we have created and requires a bit of hacks.  Is there anything I can use that would avoid using that tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What *Parse error*?

The CREATE will fail due to double `INTEGER` in `MyColId` and `VARCHAR(max)` in `ExceptionOutput`, it's an unknown datatype in Teradata.

Comment: I corrected those mistakes but get this error: [Teradata Database] [3706] Syntax error: expected something between ';' and the 'IF' keyword.  I'm updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Of course, `IF` is part of BTEQ syntax, you need to move the logic into PowerShell. Run the Select, check if it returns a row, otherwise run the CREATE...

Comment: Ok.  That confirms my understanding that there is nothing within any tooling to use this other than via BTEQ or do the logic on my side prior to execution.